# Cleaner WHERE for current month and day in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a cleaner/shorter/more readable way to add a `WHERE` statement for a query with the current day and month combo.

```
SELECT id, name, dob, (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(dob)) AS age 
FROM people
WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW())
```

For example;

```
WHERE dob = THISDAY()
```

Comment: Might wanna ask this in [codereview.se]

Comment: Why what is it that you dont like about this approach?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to add 'shorter/more readble'. I didn't really mean 'clean' as in per code reviews, but something less convulated.

Comment: 'cleaner' solution is still messy. plus, if your database optimizes caches, then there is nothing wrong with your implementation. you can experiment with something like `WHERE dob like '%MONTH(NOW())-DAY(NOW())';`  but I don't think that you will find anything 'clean'.

Comment: Why not just say `WHERE dob = CURRDATE()` or `WHERE dob = NOW()` considering your dob is datetime column. BTW, I don't see anything wrong with your approach though.

Comment: `CURDATE` and  `NOW` won't work for birthdays/getting age. But I guess my current approach is okay then.

Answer (score 0):

People born on Feb. 29th generally celebrate their birthday on the 60th day, regardless of the calendar date (May 1st on non-leap years).

While not shorter, this method doesn't leave out those born on Feb. 29:

```
SELECT id, name, dob, (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(dob)) AS age 
FROM people
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) =
  DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(dob)) YEAR))
```

Leap years are the reason there is no simple method like `DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) = DAYOFYEAR(dob)`.

Comment: Good consideration. However my use case is "Who has registered on this date" and I kinda already gave up on those Feb 29th people. I might just add a second query when the current day is Feb 28th.

Comment: Strange that "dob" means "registration date". Regardless of whether it's a "registration date" or a "birth date", isn't the solution the same?

Comment: Yes it is, but my views/design don't allow for leapdays on non-leapyears. So I either have to update the design or ignore those people. I just did a quick check, 16 out of 25k people have a feb 29th.